# Facing ActiveRecord::NotNullViolation Exception: PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR: null value in column "item_id" violates not-null constraint

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6.1

I am facing `ActiveRecord::NotNullViolation Exception: PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column "item_id" violates not-null constraint` error while attempting to create attempts for from the controller. I have no idea how to resolve this error. Any help would be appreciated. I tried googling around to no avail. There was an issue raised in the `paper_trail` gem's repository in 2019 by `pedrofurtado` which suggested the removal of `gem 'activerecord-suppress_range_error'` which I am not using.

My controller looks like -

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

class AttemptsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_training
  before_action :set_attempt, only: [:update]

  def new
    @attempt = Attempt.new
    @questions = @training.questions
    skip_authorization
  end

  def create
    @attempt = @training.attempts.new(attempt_params)
    @attempt.option_id << attempt_params[:option_id]
    byebug
    @attempt.save
    skip_authorization
  end

  private

  def attempt_params
    params.require(:attempt).permit(:question_id, :user_id, :option_id)
  end

  def set_attempt
    @attempt = Attempt.find(params[:id])
  end

  def set_training
    @training = Training.find(params[:training_id])
  end
end
```

Migration -

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

class CreateAttempts < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    create_table :attempts, type: :uuid do |t|
      t.references :user, type: :uuid, index: true, foreign_key: true, null: false
      t.references :training, type: :uuid, index: true, foreign_key: true, null: false
      t.string :option_id, array: true, default: [], null: false
      t.string :question_id, null: false

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

My rails version is `6.1.3`.
Ruby version is `2.7.5`
Paper trail gem's version is `11.0`

Comment: where is item_id defined?

Comment: In the version table created by the paper trail gem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this one myself. The issue was the attempts table whose id was not set to UUID, and the versions table where the `item_id` was defined was refusing to update it because when the instance of attempts was not being saved it was rolling back. Instead of setting the id as UUID, I had set the table's type as UUID.